# How to blade date from database null or not

Tags: php, laravel, date, input, laravel-blade

I have a value in in my database Here table name: Shift and column name: From. I want to give condition in blade that if shift table's From column's value is not null then my data from "From"column will be displayed on date type input field. I used it in above way but it doesn't work

```
value="@if(!empty($shift->From)) {{$shift->From}} @endif"
```

But I got mm/dd/yyyy value in display
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0so2q.png)

Comment: You should just be able to do `value="{{ $shift->From }}"`; if `$shift->From` is `null`, it will fallback to an empty string `''`.

Comment: how can i check $shift->From is null or not. I did in a way that i attached in my question but it didn't work

Comment: What database column type is the From field?  Do you cast it to Carbon in the model?  Are you using native browser date picker or some other library?

Comment: I'm saying you don't have to; with the code I posted, if `$shift->From` is `null`, you'll see the placeholder. Please read my comment more carefully. If that comment and Snapey's answer aren't doing it, you'll need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73820001/edit) with more debugging details, such as `dump($shift->From)`, so we can see what that is. Also, please stop saying "didn't work"; that statement is almost completely useless without more context; what is happening vs what are you expecting to happen, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the old helper incase there are validation errors.

The second parameter of the `old()` helper is the initial or default value

```
value="{{ old('from', $shift->From) }}"
```

(the above assumes that your field is called `from`.  Adapt it to suit.

If you need the date formatted in a specific format, for instance to allow it to be used by a date picker, then probably easiest to create an accessor on the Shift model.

Comment: I have a value in in my database Here table name: Shift and column name: From. I want to give condition in blade that if shift table's From column's value is not null then my data from "From"column will be displayed on date type input field. I used it in above way but it doesn't work

Comment: doesn't work covers a multitude of things.  What is in the generated html (view source in the browser and paste  the relevant part to your question

Comment: yeah i edited it can you please check again

Comment: Please follow the guidance.  I didn't ask for a screenshot of the page

Comment: Are you sure your database column is `From` and not `from` ?

Comment: yeah i'm sure column name "From"

Comment: I updated my answer as the value should be quoted.